# How to hide a column in backpack-laravel with searchable

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-backpack

I'm using very very old backpack version with laravel 5, Is there any way to hide a specific column [*$this->crud->setColumns*] but still make it searchable?
**visibleInTable** will not work here as it's a legacy version of backpack.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried using style to hide - but didn't work as well as hidden tag.

Comment: what is your backpack version?

Comment: Can you share the version and also a piece of your code?

Comment: Backpack/curd version 2.0
`$this->crud->setColumns([
     ['name' => 'id', 'label' => 'ID'],
     ['name' => 'code', 'label' => 'Code'],
     ['name' => 'name', 'label' => 'Name'],
     ['name' => 'email', 'label' => 'Email']
]);`

_I just need to hide the code column from table list but want it to searchable_

Comment: You can try to set the column type to `hidden` - maybe that will work. But I really don't remember that much back into the past, sorry. That version is so old that we don't even have the docs to it online.

Comment: @tabacitu, I have tried that **hidden** it's not working. Is there any way to customise search function inside vendor folder, I know it's not ideal but there is no option as it's very old library.

Comment: I really don’t remember that far back. But you should be able use your own CrudController or ListOperation trait, that extends the one in the vendor directory. That will allow you to override almost anything you want, yes.